# Drupal Rule to deselect radio button item?

Tags: rules

In [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), I don't see any option to deselect radio button items.

In my rule, I want an **Action** which is to deselect 'Request Resubmission', as in this screenprint.

[image: screen capture]

Comment: I think you'd better to mention more details , most important you should mention what entity your check-box is attached to? is it attached to a node or a user or ... ?

Answer (score 2):

There is none that I'm aware of.

Radio buttons aren't meant to be deselected (a single selection is required). I would suggest using checkboxes to deselect an option or add a "None" option to your radio group.

Comment: Ok, if I were to use checkboxes instead, how do I still get the Rule to uncheck?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your rule. Did you try simply clearing the value of the field?

Comment: No solution. I'm exploring some modules that hopefully will help.

Comment: Hi, Sands. Sorry to hear you're still working on your problem. However your original question about radio buttons was answered. If you have moved on to checkboxes, that is a different problem and a different set of questions. That is how this site works.